"Ends are right adjoint functors to the hom functor"
That's what it says in the nlab, but it doesn't make sense. It defines $$\text{hom}: X \to \text{Fun}(C^\text{op} \times C, X)$$which doesn't make sense intuitively, so it clarifies that it sends an object $x \in X$ to the functor $C^\text{op} \times C \to X$ that sends $(c,d) \in C^\text{op} \times C$ to$$\coprod_{\text{hom}(c,d)}x=\text{hom}(c,d)\otimes x$$Unfortunately I have no idea what either side of this is supposed to mean. The left hand side suggests we are taking a coproduct over all morphisms $c \to d$, but what in tarnation is the $x$ doing? Similarly the right hand side makes no sense as $\text{hom}(c,d)$ is a set and the tensor product of a set with an object of an arbitrary category doesn't make sense. The article mentions enriched category theory frequently, so it makes sense that $X$ should be the base of enrichment, but this section introduces $X$ as "a category" and there is no other mention of enrichment.
I have not found any other characterization of taking ends as adjoint to something, but it seems convenient, so I want to ask for clarification.

Let's clarify some things.
Firstly, calling this functor "$\hom$" is slightly misleading, since it's not the ordinary $C^{op} \times C \to \mathrm{Set}$ hom functor. But it is closely related. For clarity, I'll use $\hom$ for this functor and $C(-, -)$ for the ordinary functor $C^{op} \times C \to \mathrm{Set}$.
In a closed monoidal category, we have a hom/tensor adjunction $C(a \otimes b, c) \cong C(a, [b, c])$. Analogously, if we replace $[b, c]$ with the ordinary external hom and replace the object $a$ with a set $S$, we get a copower: $\mathrm{Set}(S, C(b, c)) \cong C(S \cdot b, c)$. You can check that this is the same universal property as the coproduct of $S$ copies of $b$.
The notation $\hom(c, d) \otimes x$ is the copower of the set $\hom(c, d)$ with the object $x$ and the result is also an object of $X$. The $x$ in $\coprod_{\hom(c, d)} x$ is a constant so it's just the coproduct of $\hom(c, d)$ copies of $x$.

So spelling that all out, saying that $\mathrm{end}$ is right adjoint to $\hom$ means that for objects $x \in X$ and functors $F: C^{op} \times C \to X$, there is a natural isomorphism $\mathrm{Fun}(C^{op} \times C, X)(\hom(x), F) \cong X(x, \mathrm{end}(F))$. Let's check that.
$$
\begin{align}
\mathrm{Fun}(C^{op} \times C, X)(\hom(x), F) & =  \mathrm{Fun}(C^{op} \times C, X)(C(-, -) \otimes x, F)\\
& \cong \int_{(c, c'): C^{op} \times C} X(C(c, c') \otimes x, F(c, c'))\\ 
& \cong \int_{(c, c'): C^{op} \times C} \mathrm{Set}(C(c, c'), X(x, F(c, c')))\\
& \cong \int_{c': C} \int_{c: C^{op}} \mathrm{Set}(C(c, c'), X(x, F(c, c'))) & \text{(Fubini)}\\
& \cong \int_{c': C} X(x, F(c', c')) & \text{(Yoneda)}\\
& \cong X(x, \int_{c': C} F(c', c'))\\
& = X(x, \mathrm{end}(F))
&
\end{align}
$$

I don’t know why people make things difficult for themselves by not using the weighted limit formalism…

@ZhenLin Do you think it would be pedagogically useful to introduce another concept here? I mean, I could, but I think it would be a less useful answer. Maybe I'll add another section with it

I meant the page the OP cited, mainly. Cotensors are weighted limits, ends are weighted limits – in a way, this is not introducing a new concept but rather unifying some.
